# Swift 3 functions naming convention

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, coding-style

I'm a little bit confused by function naming convention in Swift 3

I went through Swift 3 Guidelines and I found that method naming convention should look like this:

```
func move(from start: Point, to end: Point)
x.move(from: x, to: y)
```

### but...

If I look on the UINavigationController methods I found `pushViewController` and `presentViewController` methods. The methods calls looks like this:

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
navigationController?.present(controller, animated: true)
```

and here I'm wondering why the `pushViewController` method call is not Swift3 like. And why there is a  inconsistency between this two methods. Due to guidelines, I think the `push` method should look like this:

```
rootNavigationController?.push(viewController, animated: true)
```

then it would be more Swift 3 like.

### Let's consider a simple example:

```
//1
func saveName(_ name : String) {}
saveName("John")

//2
func save(_ name: String){}
save("John")

//3
func save(name: String){}
save(name: "John")
```

In my opinion, I think the option number 3 fits the most to the Swift 3 Guidelines. 
 But on the other hand due to my example with `pushViewController` and `present(controller)` methods the option number 1 is good too.

### So my question is:

Which is the best option that fits the Swift 3 Guidelines the most?

## UPDATE

Due to @Sweeper answer, it solves why there is an inconsistency between `push` and `present` methods.

#### Sources:

https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide

https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#parameter-names

Comment: You said magic word - opinion. iOS frameworks were written long before Swift came along. It is expected that there will be discrepancies between official Swift guidelines and existing code-bases.

Comment: Totally agree, but this discrepancies brings some confusions and that's why I got some thoughts about it.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114956/why-isnt-viewwithtag-and-some-other-methods-renamed-in-swift-3

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, it probably solves why the there is an inconsistency between `present` and `push` method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please have a look at here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md

It says that:

> **- Never prune a suffix from the base name of a method that matches a
> property of the enclosing class:**
>
> This heuristic has the effect of
> preventing us from producing too-generic names for methods that
> conceptually modify a property of the class.
>
> ... If we were to drop GestureRecognizer, leaving just add, we end up
> with a method that conceptually modifies the gestureRecognizers
> property but uses an overly generic name to do so:

This is why `pushViewController` was not renamed. In `UINavigationController`, there is a property called `viewControllers`. To avoid an "overly generic name".

Why was `present` renamed then?

Note that `present` is defined in `UIViewController`. `UIViewController` does not have a property called `viewController` or `viewControllers`, so the `ViewController` part gets pruned.

Answer (score 3):

## Inconsistency:

- Much of the `UIKit` and `Foundation` frameworks have been built in `Objective-C` and have existed before `Swift`.
- So they have a Swift interface to access them, most of the places they have tried to match it and yes at times there is inconsistency.

## Goal:

It is perfectly ok to have functions with or without external parameter name. It depends on the scenario (class, function and context)

The goal is to define the function name in such a way that the function name alone (without the parameters) describes what the function will do.

Look at from the usage and how it would be invoked. A clear name really can improve readability and pave way for a good design (avoiding confusion over where a function belongs in class `A` or class `B`

## Example:

```
struct Record {
    
    var name : String
    var age : Int
    
    func save() {}
}
```

- In this case, it is might make sense not to have any parameters at all as `name` and `age` are properties in `Record`
- So the class / struct / enum also adds context, so unnecessary / redundant words can be avoided.
- Functions with side effects are represented with verbs
- Functions without side effects are represented with nouns
- Refer the below link for mutating and non-mutating functions.

Answer:

So it depends on the context and try to look at the usage of the API, that would give more insights how you can design your API.

`record.save()`

**Note**: The above is just an example, may be in your scenario `save` function might be part of a different context.

## Reference:

https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/